# DIY electronics projects powered by Sony NPF batteries

Tags: batteries, diy

I'm looking into making some DIY projects to be powered by the Sony NPF series of batteries. These batteries are usually found in photography and video equipment.

The issue is **I can't seem to find detailed specs on these NPF standards**.

I know the nominal voltage is 7.2V and capacity varies by the size of the battery itself. Everything else, I'm in the dark.

- Are there protections built into the batteries like short-circuit?
- Is there a mechanical mounting dimension available so I can design and 3D print the mount, or does Sony only release these info to approved third party manufacturers?

Comment: ask sony for the information

Comment: There are DIY battery "plates" for these. (Found them easily.) I'd just get a few of these and try them out. When I settled on one I liked, I'd use calipers and take measurements for the plate and then use stetchup (v8 free version from what google still gave it away) and add Ruby code to validate the design I create for the 3D printer. Then I'd make some project boxes and try them out. (I've done something like this many times for other kinds of battery cases (AAA, AA, etc.) So long as there are some folks out there making cheap "plates" you can either buy them to use or buy them to measure.

Comment: @jonk So basically I have to reverse engineer their mounting plate from one already on the market.

Comment: @jsotola Guess I can try that. Will have to find the right department to ask.

Comment: you could also ask at https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kuan I've no idea. But I would NOT be bothered at all if that were the case. Of course, your feelings are your own. That's just mine. But I've never let something like that bother me. In fact, when I needed a printer I just took an old typewriter and pulled it apart, studied its operation and reverse engineered out the details, added a few things to it, and had my printer. Worked perfectly, first time. Worked many years after. A wimpy "plate?" That wouldn't even cross my mind as a difficulty. I'd just take a moment and get it done.

Comment: @Kuan Someone accidentally broke a towel rack a few months ago. I didn't go to the store. I just looked around and noticed a couple of old, bent-up pipes (they'd been smashed together by kids to make sounds) going out to recycling. I grabbed those up, measured them, and then designed this [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVMfk.png). Then I went out and got some olds bits of oak (just a scrap) and [put together this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adxPS.jpg) in short order. Micrometers work fine. Imagination works fine. Just do it. The copper bands are just refrigerator tubing smashed on an anvil.

Comment: @jonk. Not saying it's a hard or bad thing. Just a bit annoying. Maybe it's just me used to getting the official dimensional drawing and modelling it on Solidworks off of that. I'll measure the plate with a caliper then. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: unless you know the proprietary protocol on these smart batteries , how can you use them?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't know the protocol. I just know the battery can supply the voltage through it's two exposed pins. Not sure what the max amp output is but I know it's at least over 1A. Never tried to short-circuit the two pins and I don't plan to anytime in the future.

Comment: @Kuan is there a specific reason you like that battery?  It looks expensive for what you get.

Comment: This smart battery can report State of charge and other diagnostics but they performed poorly for me at temperatures near freezing.

Comment: @KH A few reasons. I already have a couple of these batteries from my photography/video gears. They provide way more voltage and current than most other standard batteries like AA. I can power things like NEMA17 steppers off of it. Since a few of my projects fall under the photography category, why not go with a common standard. They're also easier/safer to handle compared to high output LiPo batteries found in RC applications.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 So you've powered things with the NPF batteries before then? What other info have you discovered about it?

Comment: They’re expensive

Comment: Compatibility with existing gear is a factor but the reason I was asking is that the best cost effect/power density assembly if you have space for it is probably 18650 Lithium Ion.  You have to build your own pack from charge/balance/protection boards, but you get a lot of power at a low cost.